# ncurses "shadow" of a window

Tags: c, shadow, ncurses

I'm learning ncurses and I ran into a "problem". I can make a window with text in it, I can change the color of the window, and the color of the background(stdscr). My problem is, that I can't make the shadow of the window (black ACS_BLOCKs). I tried the `border()/wborder()` functions, but it didn't do what I expect. So I want something like this:

[image: the Shadow is looking at you]

Comment: If you solve your problem, write the solution as an answer to your original question and then mark it as correct.  This removes the question from the lists of unanswered question.  If it is a really useful answer you can even earn a badge for it: *Answered your own question with score of 3 or more*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: I figured it out myself:

```
WINDOW *create_window(int y, int x, int width, int height, int color_id){
    WINDOW* win;
    int i;

    win = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    wbkgd(win, A_NORMAL | COLOR_PAIR(color_id) | ' ');

    /* start of shadow */
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));

    for(i = (x + 2); i < (x + width + 1); i++){
        move((y + height), i);
        addch(' ');
    }

    for(i = (y + 1); i < (y + height + 1); i++){
        move(i, (x + width));
        addch(' ');
        move(i, (x + width + 1));
        addch(' ');
    }
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
    /* end of shadow */

    refresh();

    return win;
}
```